# How to log from core project

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

Consider an application **`A`** which logs to `/some/directory/A/logs/a.log`
Consider an application **`B`** which logs to `/some/directory/B/logs/b.log`

And consider an application **`C`** which is packaged as a jar and used in **`A`** and **`B`**.

How do we log from application **`C`** - seeing as both application **`A`** and **`B`** have their own `log4j.properties` file in the resources file.

Should Application **`C`** somehow share the `log4j.properties` from the **`A`** and **`B`** projects and if so how would i structure my `log4j.properties` file. Currently I have the following properties files in resources directory for **`A`** and **`B`**

```
log=/some/directory/A/logs/a.log
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.append=true log4j.appender.FILE.file=${log}
log4j.appender.FILE.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle log4j is configured by a single `log4j.properties` file. If **`A`** and **`B`** are web applications will have its own classloader. Each classloader finds the file independently. If the application and the core have its own file, the loader can only load one.

Comment: in which case, how can you say application A and B both have their own log4j properties and when core/C needs to log it should use the relevant one based on which application C is embedded in